# Cannot create cluster on ScyllaDB

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, jmx, scylla

I just got started with ScyllaDB (on Windows 10, using Docker). Everything is fine when I create a node (docker run --name Node_X -d scylladb/scylla:4.1.0)

But when I create another one that I link to the 1st one (docker run --name Node_Y -d scylladb/scylla:4.1.0 --seeds="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' Node_X)").

It returns an error message: "nodetool: Unable to connect to Scylla API server: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help '".

Many thanks for your help.

Guillaume

One can find the logs for the 2nd node below:

> running: (['/opt/scylladb/scripts/scylla_dev_mode_setup',
> '--developer-mode', '1'],) running:
> (['/opt/scylladb/scripts/scylla_io_setup'],) 2020-12-28 14:07:02,470
> CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped
> because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run
> as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this
> message. 2020-12-28 14:07:02,470 INFO Included extra file
> "/etc/supervisord.conf.d/node-exporter.conf" during parsing 2020-12-28
> 14:07:02,471 INFO Included extra file
> "/etc/supervisord.conf.d/rsyslog.conf" during parsing 2020-12-28
> 14:07:02,471 INFO Included extra file
> "/etc/supervisord.conf.d/scylla-housekeeping.conf" during parsing
> 2020-12-28 14:07:02,471 INFO Included extra file
> "/etc/supervisord.conf.d/scylla-jmx.conf" during parsing 2020-12-28
> 14:07:02,471 INFO Included extra file
> "/etc/supervisord.conf.d/scylla-server.conf" during parsing 2020-12-28
> 14:07:02,471 INFO Included extra file
> "/etc/supervisord.conf.d/sshd-server.conf" during parsing 2020-12-28
> 14:07:02,504 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized 2020-12-28
> 14:07:02,504 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP
> authentication checking 2020-12-28 14:07:02,504 INFO supervisord
> started with pid 26 2020-12-28 14:07:03,507 INFO spawned: 'scylla'
> with pid 29 2020-12-28 14:07:03,509 INFO spawned:
> 'scylla-housekeeping' with pid 30 2020-12-28 14:07:03,511 INFO
> spawned: 'sshd' with pid 31 2020-12-28 14:07:03,512 INFO spawned:
> 'scylla-jmx' with pid 32 2020-12-28 14:07:03,514 INFO spawned:
> 'rsyslog' with pid 33 2020-12-28 14:07:03,515 INFO spawned:
> 'node-exporter' with pid 34 Generating public/private ed25519 key
> pair. Your identification has been saved in
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key. Your public key has been saved in
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub. The key fingerprint is:
> SHA256:h6ScBFQ3ZuJpK3F0GZUTfOmLinXX1+LxW7B8rxOx5FM root@f881e3d82b89
> The key's randomart image is:
> +--[ED25519 256]--+ |   .o.+ B=oo .   | |     + B..+ o    | |    . * .  +     | |     * = .  . o E| |    . = S .. =.+.| |     .  ..o o.Ooo| |       o o . .oBo| |      . .     o.+| |              .+o|
> +----[SHA256]-----+ time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg="Starting node_exporter (version=0.17.0, branch=HEAD,
> revision=f6f6194a436b9a63d0439abc585c76b19a206b21)"
> source="node_exporter.go:82" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg="Build context (go=go1.11.2, user=root@322511e06ced,
> date=20181130-15:51:33)" source="node_exporter.go:83"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg="Enabled collectors:"
> source="node_exporter.go:90" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - arp" source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z"
> level=info msg=" - bcache" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - bonding"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - conntrack" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - cpu"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - diskstats" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - edac"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - entropy" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - filefd"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - filesystem" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - hwmon"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - infiniband" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - interrupts"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - ipvs" source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z"
> level=info msg=" - loadavg" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - mdadm"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - meminfo" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - netclass"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - netdev" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - netstat"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - nfs" source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z"
> level=info msg=" - nfsd" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - sockstat"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - stat" source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z"
> level=info msg=" - textfile" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - time"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - timex" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - uname"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - vmstat" source="node_exporter.go:97"
> time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info msg=" - xfs"
> source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z" level=info
> msg=" - zfs" source="node_exporter.go:97" time="2020-12-28T14:07:03Z"
> level=info msg="Listening on :9100" source="node_exporter.go:111"
> /etc/scylla.d/docker.conf: line 1: docker: command not found FATAL:
> Exception during startup, aborting:
> boost::wrapexceptboost::bad_lexical_cast (bad lexical cast: source
> type value could not be interpreted as target) 2020-12-28 14:07:03,984
> INFO exited: scylla (exit status 7; not expected) Connecting to
> http://localhost:10000 Starting the JMX server Generating
> public/private rsa key pair. Your identification has been saved in
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key. Your public key has been saved in
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub. The key fingerprint is:
> SHA256:q+U05wLwl2LeoE98MrGp7MHuEpk4021nzP+TKeIVZbM root@f881e3d82b89
> The key's randomart image is:
> +---[RSA 4096]----+ |                 | |                 | |          +      | |    .    o o     | | o + =. S.E      | |+ =.o.@+oo       | | o oo*BBB .o     | |  .o.+oX=++      | |   +*o+..+o.     |
> +----[SHA256]-----+ Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key JMX is enabled to receive remote
> connections on port: 7199 2020-12-28 14:07:05,423 INFO spawned:
> 'scylla' with pid 73 2020-12-28 14:07:05,424 INFO success:
> scylla-housekeeping entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for >
> than 1 seconds (startsecs) 2020-12-28 14:07:05,424 INFO success: sshd
> entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds
> (startsecs) 2020-12-28 14:07:05,424 INFO success: scylla-jmx entered
> RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
> 2020-12-28 14:07:05,424 INFO success: rsyslog entered RUNNING state,
> process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs) 2020-12-28
> 14:07:05,424 INFO success: node-exporter entered RUNNING state,
> process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
> /etc/scylla.d/docker.conf: line 1: docker: command not found FATAL:
> Exception during startup, aborting:
> boost::wrapexceptboost::bad_lexical_cast (bad lexical cast: source
> type value could not be interpreted as target) 2020-12-28 14:07:05,979
> INFO exited: scylla (exit status 7; not expected) 2020-12-28
> 14:07:07,986 INFO spawned: 'scylla' with pid 181
> /etc/scylla.d/docker.conf: line 1: docker: command not found FATAL:
> Exception during startup, aborting:
> boost::wrapexceptboost::bad_lexical_cast (bad lexical cast: source
> type value could not be interpreted as target) 2020-12-28 14:07:08,525
> INFO exited: scylla (exit status 7; not expected)
> multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:  """ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319,
> in do_open
> encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in
> request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line
> 1298, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in
> endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line
> 1026, in _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in
> send
> self.connect()   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 938, in
> connect
> (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 728, in
> create_connection
> raise err   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in
> create_connection
> sock.connect(sa) OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line
> 121, in worker
> result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "/opt/scylladb/scripts/libexec/scylla-housekeeping", line 64, in
> get_url
> return urllib.request.urlopen(path).read().decode('utf-8')   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222,
> in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525,
> in open
> response = self._open(req, data)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543,
> in _open
> '_open', req)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503,
> in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1347,
> in http_open
> return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1321,
> in do_open
> raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address> """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/scylladb/scripts/libexec/scylla-housekeeping", line 197, in
>
> args.func(args)   File "/opt/scylladb/scripts/libexec/scylla-housekeeping", line 123, in
> check_version
> current_version = sanitize_version(get_api('/storage_service/scylla_release_version'))
> File "/opt/scylladb/scripts/libexec/scylla-housekeeping", line 82, in
> get_api
> return get_json_from_url("http://" + api_address + path)   File "/opt/scylladb/scripts/libexec/scylla-housekeeping", line 74, in
> get_json_from_url
> retval = result.get(timeout=5)   File "/opt/scylladb/python3/lib64/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line
> 657, in get
> raise self._value urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address> 2020-12-28 14:07:12,202 INFO spawned:
> 'scylla' with pid 216 /etc/scylla.d/docker.conf: line 1: docker:
> command not found FATAL: Exception during startup, aborting:
> boost::wrapexceptboost::bad_lexical_cast (bad lexical cast: source
> type value could not be interpreted as target) 2020-12-28 14:07:12,727
> INFO exited: scylla (exit status 7; not expected) 2020-12-28
> 14:07:13,729 INFO gave up: scylla entered FATAL state, too many start
> retries too quickly

Answer (score 0):

I shared your post with ScyllaDB engineers. Hopefully they will respond here. If you want, you can also post your question in our community slack here:

http://slack.scylladb.com/

Or our user group:

https://groups.google.com/g/scylladb-users

Comment: Hello Peter,

I asked the Slack channel a few days ago, I'll do the same on the Google group.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Most welcome. Please return here and share whatever answer you get. If you don't get any, return here and I'll poke people to get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your port forwarding is likely to be wrong, the two instances need to connect, how's your docker invocation line looks like?

Comment: Hello dor laor, 

I don't exactly know what you mean by that but here is what I do.

I simply execute Docker Desktop, open cmd and run:
docker run --name Node_X -d scylladb/scylla:4.1.0



Node_X appears in my nodes list, Node_Y as well but cannot be linked.

Cheers